# Convert any number WITH DECIMALS to corresponding word

Tags: fmtcount

I want to put in words a value that has a decimal part. I am using numberstringnum, it works fine without decimals, any one can help me?

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper,times,hidelinks,unicode]{report}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\begin{document}
\numberstringnum{985.25}
\end{document}
```

Comment: How do you want the decimal part to be spelled out?

Answer (score 4):

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{\xfoo#1..\relax}
\def\xfoo#1.#2.#3\relax{%
\numberstringnum{#1}%
\if$#2$\else
\space point%
% .10 -> point one zero
\@tfor\tmp:=#2\do{ \numberstringnum{\tmp}}%
% .10 -> point ten % if you _really_ need this
% 
\fi
}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\foo{985}

\foo{985.25}

\end{document}
```

---

babel aware version:

[image]

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[english,ngerman]{babel}

\makeatletter
\def\foo#1{\xxfoo#1,,\relax}
\def\xxfoo#1,#2,{\xfoo#1.#2.}
\def\xfoo#1.#2.#3\relax{%
\numberstringnum{#1}%
\if$#2$\else
\space\pointname
% .10 -> point one zero
\@tfor\tmp:=#2\do{ \numberstringnum{\tmp}}%
% .10 -> point ten % if you _really_ need this
% \numberstringnum{#2}%
\fi
}
\def\pointname{point}
\addto\extrasngerman{\def\pointname{Komma}}
\addto\extrasenglish{\def\pointname{point}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}

\foo{985}

\foo{985.25}

\foo{985,25}

\selectlanguage{english}

\foo{985}

\foo{985.25}

\foo{985,25}



\end{document}
```

Comment: Add `\usepackage[ngerman]{babel}` and change `point` to `Komma`, you get a German version ... So, maybe add an optional parameter where you can set the word for the decimal?

Comment: @JasperHabicht Frag Ulrike, sie weiß, dass ich fließend Deutsch spreche:-) Better would be to replace `point` by `\pointname`  then like other fixed `...name` texts you could do `\addtoextras{ngerman}{\def\pointame{Komma}}` or whatever (you might also want to split the input on `,` in that case, which is possible of course.

Comment: @JasperHabicht suitably long word generated, see update.

Comment: thanks, it works, but I would like the decimals not to be read individually. I mean: Nine Hundred and eighty-five point Twenty Five, instead o "Two five".

Comment: @Carlos you could do that of course just replace the loop by `\numberstringnum{#2}` but that is just completely wrong  why would you automate that? You should never read 1.10 as 1 point _ten_

Comment: @Carlos that is replace `\@tfor\tmp:=#2\do{ \numberstringnum{\tmp}}%` by `\space\numberstringnum{#2}%` but I would strongly recommend against that

Comment: Thanks so much, it works great. The thing with "twenty-five" is for languages issues (I am doing it in Spanish)

Comment: @Carlos Podría decir que mi español es tan bueno como mi alemán :-)

Comment: In German, saying "neunhundertfünfundachtzig Komma fünfundzwanzig" would be wrong as well (although there surely exist people who would do that). I really don't like written numbers in German anyways ... they are hard to read even for Germans (at least for me ...).

Comment: @JasperHabicht https://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/19701043#19701043

Comment: @Carlos In Spanish, wouldn't you take every two numbers together after the decimal, such as 5.2532 being read as "cinco punto/coma veinticinco treinta y dos" (five point twenty-five thirty-two)?

Comment: Thanks for your help @DavidCarlisle, one more thing. I am trying to get an element from a table, and then write it into words. I am using your code but it seems that I do not understand the code. I am a beginner in Latex, but I know some coding (Matlab, lispt, etc). So After the preamble I wrote: \begin{document}
\pgfplotstableread{AAAT.tex}\dataA
\pgfplotstablegetelem{14}{[index]4}\of\dataA
\def\AAAA{\pgfplotsretval}
\foo{\AAAA}
\end{document}

Comment: @Carlos try replacing `\def\AAAA{\pgfplotsretval} \foo{\AAAA}` by `\expandafter\foo\expandafter{\pgfplotsretval}`

Answer (score 0):

I am not sure whether such practice is official or rather informal, but in some countries it seems to be common to read decimals in groups of two. So, I thought the following might be useful:

```
\documentclass[12pt,a4paper]{report}
\usepackage{fmtcount}
\usepackage[english, ngerman, spanish]{babel}

\ExplSyntaxOn

\prop_new:N \l_floattostring_settings_prop
\NewDocumentCommand { \floattostringlocals } { m } {
    \prop_set_from_keyval:Nn \l_floattostring_settings_prop { 
        decimal~separator = point, 
        word~separator = \space, 
        group~decimals = 1
    }
    \prop_put_from_keyval:Nn \l_floattostring_settings_prop { #1 }
}

\addto\extrasenglish{ \floattostringlocals { } }

\cs_new_protected:Nn \floattostring_regex_extractdigitgroups:nnN {
    \regex_extract_all:nnN { \d{#1} | \d+ \z } { #2 } #3
}
\cs_generate_variant:Nn \floattostring_regex_extractdigitgroups:nnN { VV }

\seq_new:N \l_floattostring_parts_seq
\tl_new:N \l_floattostring_integer_tl
\tl_new:N \l_floattostring_decimals_tl
\int_new:N \l_floattostring_groupdecimals_int
\seq_new:N \l_floattostring_decimalsgroups_seq
\NewDocumentCommand { \floattostring } { m } {
    \seq_clear:N \l_floattostring_parts_seq
    \regex_split:nnN { \. | \, } { #1 } \l_floattostring_parts_seq
    \seq_get_left:NN \l_floattostring_parts_seq \l_floattostring_integer_tl
    
    \numberstringnum{ \l_floattostring_integer_tl }
    
    \int_compare:nNnTF { \seq_count:N \l_floattostring_parts_seq } > { 1 } {
        \prop_item:Nn \l_floattostring_settings_prop { word~separator }
        \prop_item:Nn \l_floattostring_settings_prop { decimal~separator }
        
        \seq_get_right:NN \l_floattostring_parts_seq \l_floattostring_decimals_tl
        \int_set:Nn \l_floattostring_groupdecimals_int 
            { \prop_item:Nn \l_floattostring_settings_prop { group~decimals } }
        
        \floattostring_regex_extractdigitgroups:VVN 
            \l_floattostring_groupdecimals_int 
            \l_floattostring_decimals_tl 
            \l_floattostring_decimalsgroups_seq
    
        \seq_map_inline:Nn \l_floattostring_decimalsgroups_seq {
            \prop_item:Nn \l_floattostring_settings_prop { word~separator }
            \numberstringnum{ ##1 }
        }
    } { } 
}
\ExplSyntaxOff

\addto\extrasngerman{\floattostringlocals{ decimal separator = Komma }}
\addto\extrasspanish{\floattostringlocals{ decimal separator = punto, group decimals = 2 }}

\begin{document}

\selectlanguage{ngerman}
\floattostring{345.2345}

\floattostring{1.234}

\selectlanguage{spanish}
\floattostring{345.2345}

\floattostring{1.234}

\selectlanguage{english}
\floattostring{345.2345}

\floattostring{1.234}

\floattostringlocals{ group decimals = 2 }
\floattostring{345.2345}

\end{document}
```

The macro `\floattostringlocals` takes as argument a key-value list that may contain the keys `decimal separator`, `word separator` and `group decimals`. The key `decimal separator` takes as value the relevant string that should be printed for the decimal separator. Using the key `word separator`, it is possible to switch to another string than a space to separate words since some languages don't use spaces to separate words. Finally, the key `group decimals` takes as value an integer that denotes how the decimals should be grouped for spelling.

In combination with `\addto\extras<language>` it is be possible to set up different spelling rules for floating numbers for different languages.

The above code would result in the following:

[image]